# Gauge transformation and Special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, gauge-theory

While explaining gauge theories, a book makes a comment that the U(1) transformation definition, $ U= e^{i q \lambda(x)}$ is analogous to a special relativity transformation in freely falling elevator. I didn't understand what the author is referring to. Please explain.